# Jquery image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagesource

I have been having some trouble making this work, I need to create an html page that has three  images in a row and a button that change all the three images to other images, and when the button is pressed  again the images switch back to the first three images from the beginning .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0):

You should load all the images into two div elements, hide one of them by default, then switch which div is shown and which is hidden whenever the button is pressed.  The jQuery click function can detect when the button is clicked, and the jQuery toggle function can switch show/hide states.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#imageSet2').hide();
})

$('#imageSetBtn').click(function(){
 $('#imageSet1').toggle();
 $('#imageSet2').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="imageSetBtn" type="button">Switch</button>

<div id="imageSet1">
 <img src="https://www.google.com/chrome/assets/common/images/chrome_logo_2x.png?mmfb=a5234ae3c4265f687c7fffae2760a907">
</div>

<div id="imageSet2">
 <img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/template/header-logo-inverse.510f97e92635.png">
</div>
```